# How to push to Github using Netbeans? (Mac)

Tags: git, netbeans, github

I've created a repository on my GitHub.
[image]

And I'm looking at these options and I have no idea how to push my current code to the Github Repository.
[image]

When I click on clone, I move it to this folder...
[image]

But then get stuck here...
[image]

When I click the initialize option and I route to the dropbox folder... 
I get this error...
[image]

I have the GitHub Mac application setup...
[image]

Isn't there just an easy button I can push to commit all the code I have in Netbeans to GitHub (without using terminal)?

Comment: sorry - couldn't resist to de-[hashtag](http://youtu.be/57dzaMaouXA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it manually, through the command line:

```
cd /path/to/your/repo
git remote add origin git@github.com:username/repo.git
```

Then relaunch your NetBeans, and you should be able to push.

You can also click on "`Specify Git Repository Location:`", and enter your GitHub repo url there.

If it is an https one, it will prompt you for your GitHub username and password.